# how can I work with digraphs and trigrpahs in bloodshed/DevC++ compiler

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, digraphs, trigraphs

In compiler trigraphs and digraphs are not replacing by the corresponding single characters.
Rather it's giving a warning something like this,

```
12:26 G:\BIN\cLang\macro2.cpp [Warning] trigraph ??= ignored, use -trigraphs to enable
```

I want to know why this type of warning is giving and how can I solve this to use trigraphs and digraphs. In what purposes they were in the language???

NOTE - I want to see how digraphs & trigraphs work, so dont tell me to not to use them because they are obsolete...
Thanks Advance

Comment: I don't know which compiler you use, but what happens if you pass "-trigraphs" as an argument as suggested?

Comment: I am using bloodeshed/DevC++ in windows 7 .. can u please tell me how to pass "-trigraphs" ??

Comment: No idea, I have never used DevC++.

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you what to do, when you invoke the compiler add option -trigraphs

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to the warning I get with gcc.

Compiled without any flags:

```
$ gcc trigraphs.c 
trigraphs.c:5:10: warning: trigraph ??= ignored, use -trigraphs to enable
```

So I add the flag suggested by the compiler:

```
$ gcc -trigraphs trigraphs.c 
$ ./a.out 
a test: #
$
```

This is my code that I stored in the file trigraphs.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        printf("a test: ??=\n");
        return 0;
}
```